# Model class not recognizing return arguments

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a model class for managing the results given by Googles Places API:

```
class PlaceSearch {

  final String description;
  final String placeId;

  PlaceSearch(this.description, this.placeId);

  factory PlaceSearch.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){

    return PlaceSearch(description: json['description'], placeId: json['place_id']);

  }
}
```

But I am getting an error at line

```
return PlaceSearch(description: json['description'], placeId: json['place_id']);
```

The error is:

```
2 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found
```

That class has been used in an older Flutter project, but now it is not working.

What should I change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't using named constructor  on `PlaceSearch(this.description, this.placeId);`

```dart
class PlaceSearch {
  final String description;
  final String placeId;

  PlaceSearch({required this.description, required this.placeId});

  factory PlaceSearch.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return PlaceSearch(
        description: json['description'], placeId: json['place_id']);
  }
}
```